# bash ssh warning when connect to raspberry: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)

Tags: bash, ssh, raspberry-pi, locale, raspbian

I tried  for example [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1346581) to solve my problem and [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1346581) too.

My problem is that when I try to connect to my Raspberry pi2, I got the following messages:

```
Linux raspberrypi 3.18.7-v7+ #755 SMP PREEMPT Thu Feb 12 17:20:48 GMT 2015 armv7l

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Sat Mar 21 13:25:48 2015 from 192.168.10.1
-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
```

Needless to say, when I try to do an "apt-get upgrade" or try to install a new application in my raspberry, I got errors relating to language. That's why I started looking for the solution...

Some additional informations:

When I typed "locale" on my raspberry I got the following messages:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ locale
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

If I write the same command on my laptop (I want to connect to raspberry from this laptop using `ssh`):

```
mirind4@mirind4-pc:~$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_NAME=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Try `dpkg-reconfigure locales` and ensure that `en_US.UTF-8` is selected.

Comment: does result of ` locale -a`   include any de_DE.* ? if no, you need to include german local on the raspberry (I had same problem but forgot how I solve it)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

ssh will forward "some" environnement var from mirind4-pc to raspberry, among them "locale" variable (which are use to print friendly date and number).

According to misc link on [Raspian](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/19854/how-can-i-change-the-locale) and [Ask Unbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33025/locale-settings-are-not-right-how-can-i-reset-them) you may need to generate local locale. From what I guess

```
sudo locale-gen de_DE.UTF-8
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

you can check immediatly after using

```
foo:~$ LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8 date +%A%B
SamstagMärz
```

I don't have my raspian, but this worked on my ubuntu

Comment: Debian and Ubuntu do this differently. `locale-gen en_US.utf8` is the Ubuntu way; on Debian this doesn't change the system configuration, only something that's harmless. `dpkg-reconfigure locales` does nothing useful on Ubuntu and provides an interface to select locales to generate on Debian.